# The request was missing an Authentication Key, Error 401

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send Notifications and Data from Postman, To FCM, to my App. However i run into this 401 Error about me missing my authentication key. I have no clue what i have done wrong, i have correctly put in my Authentication key so i am very confused as to what is going on. Can someone please help.

[I Followed this Tutorial](https://apoorv487.medium.com/testing-fcm-push-notification-through-postman-terminal-part-1-5c2df94e6c8d)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a rather silly mistake. Simply i needed to put **my values in Header, not Params**